# if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)>0$, then there exists an open interval $I$ containing $a$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in I$.

Tags: real-analysis

This seems so true but can I prove this problem by contrapositive? and then make a graph.

But I don't know how to prove this by the definition.

Comment: *Hint:* Find an $\epsilon$ for which

$$0 < | x - a | < \delta(\epsilon) \ \Rightarrow f(x) > 0$$

Comment: put $\epsilon=\frac{l}{2}$

Comment: Actually you don't know anything about $f(a)$ itself.

Comment: $f:\R\to\R$ be a function.

Comment: Not true unless you know $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$ (think of a single discontinuity with $f(a)=-1$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\lim_{x \to a}f(x)>0$. Then set $\epsilon=\frac{L}{2}>0$. Directly from the definition of a limit, we get that there exists a $\delta$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon=\frac{L}{2}$. Since $L-f(x)\leq|f(x)-L|$, we get that $L-f(x)<\frac{L}{2}$ and thus $f(x)>\frac{L}{2}>0$.
So the interval you are looking for is $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$.

As it was mentioned in the comments, this doesn't take into account the value of $f(a)$. If $f(a)$ is negative then the statement is clearly false, so in order for this to work it must be true that $f(a)$ is defined and $f(a)>0$

Comment: This assumes continuity of $f$. Edit: it assumes some prior knowledge of $f(a)$, which isn't given.

Comment: It doesn't assume continuity in entirely; I believe that it just assumes $f(a)$ is defined and $f(a)>0$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks guys